# Counting 1's in a 2D array of 1's and 0's with O(n) complexity

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Assume a 2D `[n][n]` matrix of 1's and 0's. All the 1's in any row should come before 0's. The number of 1's in any row `i` should be at least the number of 1's row `i+1`. Find a method and write a Java program with O(n) complexity to count the 1'sin the array.

For example we have the following array:

```
{{1,1,1,1},
 {1,1,1,1},
 {1,1,0,0},
 {1,0,0,0}}
```

I have written a code that counts the 1's correctly but I am not sure if the complexity is O(n) or O(n^2).

The code is the following:

```
public class SpecialMatrix {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] a = {{1,1,1,1},
                     {1,1,1,1},
                     {1,1,0,0},
                     {1,0,0,0}};
        
        int n = 4;
        int cnt=0;
        int row; 
        int col = 0;
        for (row = n-1; row>=0; row--)
        {
            while(col<n && a[row][col]==1)
            {
                cnt = cnt + (row + 1);
                System.out.print("Row: " + row + " Col: " + col + " Cnt: " + cnt);
                System.out.println();
                col++;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.print(cnt);
        
    }
        
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Row: 3 Col: 0 Cnt: 4

Row: 2 Col: 1 Cnt: 7

Row: 1 Col: 2 Cnt: 9
Row: 1 Col: 3 Cnt: 11


11
```

I would like some help regarding the complexity of the code. Is it O(n) or O(n^2)?

Thanks!

Comment: You can indeed speed up the algorithm to achieve a linear time complexity by utilizing the given constraints:
1. All the 1's in any row should come before 0's. 
2. The number of 1's in any row i should be at least the number of 1's row i+1.
For example traversing only the rightmost 1s in the matrix and summing the column index + 1 together will give you an answer in linear time (if your algorithm is traversing optimally)

Comment: @aa_nador isn't the posted code kind of doing that??

Comment: This algorithm is O(n). You make, at most, a single pass through your input data.

Comment: If the input is an `n`x`n` matrix, and we iterate over all elements, then by definition that's n^2 because that's how many elements there are?

Comment: Not sure if you can reduce the overall complexity but you can compress the data by encoding them as bits of a 64 bit integer. But that means space would become `n*n/64`. Now in c++ `__builtin__popcount` can be used to count number of set bits of a 64 bit numbers. Even though the theoretical complexity of `__builtin__popcount` is O(no_of_bits) but it would still be lot faster than then counting via looping over 64 numbers and random accessing 64 memory locations (I am not familiar with Java's `integer.bitcount()` but my guess is it would be similar to C++'s `__builtin__popcount`).

Comment: Having said that how do you get this `n*n` data in the first place ? is it generated by another program which feeds into your desired one or are you reading the `n*n` data from console or file system? If i/o needed then even if you speed up the algorithm the program will be I/O bound ie I/O  time  will determine time of your program.

Comment: BIT packing would help only if you need to do that several times(>n) but read the data only once.

Comment: the code does NOT iterate over all elements (at most `n + (n-1)` elements - addition, not multiplication, that is `O(n)`) - please note that `col`, the *counter* of the inner loop, is **not** reset inside the outer loop

Comment: @ishandutta2007 the `n*n` array is not generated by any other program. At least for now. But even if it was generated this program would take the array as input. The array won't be created in the program but we will initialize it like in this example. So I only care about the complexity of the algorithm itself and not about how the array was produced.

Comment: @user16320675 Firstly the `col`  which is the counter in not reset inside the outer loop because we don't want the loop to start from the first column every time but from the one it stopped on the previous iteration. Secondly so can you explain a little bit more why we don't iterate through all the all elements. I get it somehow but I still have a difficulty to understand it completely. Thanks!

Comment: @VictorWilson can you explain a little bit more why we make, at most, a single pass through the input data. Thanks!

Comment: @m2r105 Firstly: and? How does that conflict with what I wrote?? (I understand the reason, but seems like some previous comments did not get it) Secondly: exactly because the counters are *going* in only one direction (up or right), it will at most get `n + (n-1)` elements (like Manhattan Distance) Or can you show a path going only up and right that traverses more elements? (other way: you at most go `n-1` **steps** up and `n-1` right, no matter of which sequence, adding `1` for the first element you get the same result)

Comment: @user16320675 OK Thanks a lot! I think I get it know!!

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That's not how algorithmic complexity works.  `n` is not an actual variable. It's simply a representation of "the input data".  "Data Structures and Algorithms" by Aho, Hopcroft, and Ullman, is an excellent resource here.

Comment: @m2r105 I think user16320675 explains it well, but put briefly, the algorithm in question will never access the same part of the array more than once. Consider the best and worst cases: a 2d array completely filled with 1s, and a 2d array completely filled with 0s. In both situations you're just making one pass through each row. And thus O(n) is achieved.

Comment: @m2r105 I think you are missing the point, you cann't say I dont care, you will have to care. If data itself is O(n*n) you can not have a algorithm less than O(n*n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer loop must *always* execute `n` times.  You can't alter that.  So as you compute the count by taking advantage of the relationship between rows, the inner while loop is governed by the `col` *and* if the current `row/col` has a `1`.  Based on the result of the `col to row` comparison, the inner loop may execute anywhere from `0 to n` times and no more.  So it is running at `O(n)`

The number of times, the inner loop is entered, and for which iteration of the outer loop, is dependent on the particular groupings of the 1's and 0's